# Magento2: Import custom attribute for specific product id using csv

Tags: product-attribute, magento-2.2.5, product-import

I am working on CSV import to add custom attribute data for Products. I have created a custom attribute as "slide_link". I am unable to add only SKU and slide_link in CSV for adding data of attribute in the product.

Please provide a solution for above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please analyse below demo its working to update price and qty using sku ( specific SKU )  via CSV, I hope its helpful to you.. ( its just idea how to work in magento2 )

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $productRepository = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
    $stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    $csv = "csvfilename.csv";
    if (!empty($argv) && sizeof($argv) > 1) {
        $csv = $argv[1];
    }
    if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            if ($num < 1) {
                continue;
            }
            $sku = trim($data[0]);
            if ($num < 2) {
                echo "Skipping: " . $sku . " not enough fields\n";
                continue;
            }
            $qty = trim($data[1]);
            $price = trim($data[2]);

            try {
                $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo "Error:  Invalid SKU, ".$sku."\n";
                continue;
            }

            if ($product->getPrice() != $price) {
                $product->setPrice($price);
                $product->save();
            }

            try {
                $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo "Error:  Invalid stock SKU, ".$sku."\n";
                continue;
            }

            if ($stockItem->getQty() != $qty) {
                $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
                }
                $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: Can u tell me how can i add dynamic custom attribute for product

Comment: Can you please explain more. Like dynamic or custom attribute

Comment: yes if  i want to set multiple custom attribute by using setData() then how can i do ?Suppose i have 3 columns sku,custom_attribute1,custom_attribute2 then without specifying name of attribute can we save it dynamically ?

Comment: Try with attribute code using foreach loop.

Comment: Can u let me know if i want to add category to product using above code how can i do it

Comment: $new_category_id = array('11','12');
 $prodid = 'productid';
$sku = $product->getSku(); // get sku using product id
// using product id than get sku... name 

 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $CategoryLinkRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
 $CategoryLinkRepository->assignProductToCategories($sku, $new_category_id);

Comment: Instead of $new_category_id = array('11','12'), if i add $new_category= Default Category/New Category then how will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why stock info is present in code of previous answer. There are easier, and surely faster, ways to update attributes values (but depending by the attribute type it could need some extra code)

Using **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action** & **\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository**

You can just do

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
$this->_action->updateAttributes(
    array($product->getId()),
    array('YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE' => $YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE),
    1
);
```

That last parameter is **store_id**, in this example: 1